# How do you configure the Tabs component to use a custom item template for the webedit button?

Tags: sxa

I have created a new item template but have not found a way for the new item web edit button (blue plus icon) to use my custom template.

As you can see, I've created a new Tab item template as well as a branch template. The primary difference in this template is the Heading changed from a Rich Text field to Single-Line Text.

[image: Templates]

I created a new datasource configuration item to address the creation of tabs.

[image: Datasource Configuration]

When adding a new tab, I see the SXA Tab Item rather than the custom one.

[image: Web edit]

Answer (score 2):

Those items which you see there in the "Insert Item" dialogue comes form insert options of Tabs (`/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Composites/Datasource/Tabs/Tabs`) item.

Take a look here:

[image]

and then:

[image]